# Rails 3 : In submit button :disable_with is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In this following code :disable_with is not working in rails 3. But it is perfectly working in rails 2.2

What is wrong in this code?

```
<%= submit_tag "Save", :class => "buttons",
                       :disable_with => "Processing",
                       :id => 'save_btn' %>
```

Comment: Did you include `jquery-rails` in your Gemfile?

Comment: yes, i have jquery-rails (2.1.4) gem

Comment: what HTML gets generated for that `submit_tag`? And what javascripts are included on that page?

Comment: SimpleForm do nothing with this feature, it's from jquery-rails gem. If you have data-disabled-with on your input actually everything should work. Are you sure you have jquery-rails gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: yes i am damn sure Using jquery-rails (2.1.4)

Comment: Try data-disable-with="Processing"

Comment: tried data-disable-with="Processing" also.. it is not working :(

Comment: Try putting the class after the disable_with.  I know it shouldn't matter, but that's how it is in the docs.

Comment: @DevinStewart it is not working bro

Comment: @suresh.g When i tried data-disable-with="Processing" it is showing a error as syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
...data-disable-with="Processing", :id => 'save_btn' );@output_...

Answer (score 6):

Since version 3.2.5 you should not use :disable_with.

```
<%= submit_tag "Save", 'data-disable-with' => "Processing", :class => "buttons", :id => 'save_btn' %>
```

or

```
<%= submit_tag "Save", data: { disable_with: "Processing" }, :class => "buttons", :id => 'save_btn' %>
```

Comment: I am using rails 3.0. both the above also not working.. OMG! really fed up!

Comment: Well for 3.0 your syntax is dead on.  The only other thing it could be is some other JavaScript associated with that class or id interfering with the action.

Comment: I noticed that, In my gem file 'jquery-rails' is commended :(

Comment: At least you have your answer :) And you know for 3.2.5 that the syntax is changed

Comment: Thanks Devin Stewart.. Actual problem is with my gem i guess!

Comment: Thanks @DevinStewart. Your answer did helped. Same information about api change is at "http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag"

Answer (score 1):

Check the following in your raw html:

- the submit button has data-disable-with attribute
- your page includes jQuery js. For me I have:

  - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
- you page includes jquery_ujs js. For me I have:

  - /javascripts/jquery_ujs.js

You can read more on https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs. Different installations for different rails versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Safari 8.0.6 and latest rails-ujs. Here's my approach of solving this issue:

```html
%button{ class: 'btn btn-action js-submit', data: { method: :put, 'href' => '...', disable_with: "<i class='icon icon-spinner icon-spin'></i>".html_safe }} Submit
```

```js
$('.js-select-plan').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $target     = $(this),
      href        = $target.data('href'),
      method      = $target.data('method'),
      formTarget  = $target.attr('target'),
      csrfToken   = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
      csrfParam   = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content'),
      form        = $('<form method="post" action="' + href + '"></form>'),
      metaData    = '<input name="_method" value="' + method + '" type="hidden" />';

  if (csrfParam !== undefined && csrfToken !== undefined) {
    metaData += '<input name="' + csrfParam + '" value="' + csrfToken + '" type="hidden" />';
  }

  if (formTarget) {
    form.attr('target', formTarget);
  }

  // disable button/link element
  var contentMethod = $target.is('button') ? 'html' : 'val';
  var replacement   = $target.data('disable-with');
  $target.data('ujs:enable-with', $target[contentMethod]());
  if (replacement !== undefined) {
    $target[contentMethod](replacement);
  }
  $target.prop('disabled', true);

  form.hide().append(metaData).appendTo('body');
  setTimeout(function(){
    form.submit();
  }, 50);
});
```

This works like a charm in all browsers. For better flexibility you might want to wrap this in a helper.